# Find the biggest Value in one row and print a different row

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am learning Python and I'm trying to print out the city with the biggest population.
I have the function where I can get the biggest population
but I don't know how can I return the city with the biggest population.

**The code I already have:**

```py
import csv
    
csvfile = open('worldcities.csv', "r", encoding="utf8")
csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
next(csv_reader, None)  # skip the headers

maxVal = []

for row in csv_reader:
    try:
        maxVal.append(float(row[9]))
    except ValueError:
        a = 1
    
print ("\nDie Stadt mit der höchsten Einwohnerzahl:", max(maxVal))
```

My CSV data:
[image: csv_data]

Comment: You either need to use argmax and use its index to find the city or you need to check if population is biggest within the loop and store the city name in a separate variable

Comment: If you want city name and it maximum population as a answer. Since you are already using a maxVal list, append city name and its population in that list using `maxVal.append((row[9], row[0]))` and then you can `print(max(maxVal)`, which prints (population number, city name)

Comment: @y051 Tahnk you for your answer. The problem is that if i dont put the float in front of row[9] I get a conpleteley different value and not the highest population.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('worldcities.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
print(df.iloc[df['population'].idxmax(), :])
```

Comment: Is it possible not to use panda for this problem?

Comment: @Marvin of course it's possible, it would be pointless to do so

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch, Marvin is asking a very reasonable question. Don't assume that everybody has pandas or NumPy at hand, or can (or wants to) install them. They are fairly heavy dependencies, and a `csv`-only, standard library-only solution is far from a "pointless" request.